# Windows CLI output in wrong language

Tags: windows, command-line, language

I have set all the language settings I possibly can in the Control Panel (Set-WinSystemLocale did nothing).

However, when I run wsl --status, it still outputs in the wrong language. German in this case. Why is this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried chcp?

```
chcp [<nnn>]
```

Documentation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp

> Changes the active console code page. If used without parameters, chcp displays the number of the active console code page.

| Code page | Country/region or language |
| --- | --- |
| 437 | United States |
| 850 | Multilingual (Latin I) |
| 852 | Slavic (Latin II) |
| 855 | Cyrillic (Russian) |
| 857 | Turkish |
| 860 | Portuguese |
| 861 | Icelandic |
| 863 | Canadian-French |
| 865 | Nordic |
| 866 | Russian |
| 869 | Modern Greek |
| 936 | Chinese |

Since wsl is a subsystem of Windows, you could try that first.

Assuming that didn't work, in wsl try checking the results from:

```
~$ locale
```

And then try changing the system via

```
~$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked. chcp is set to 437. The WSL locales are C.UTF-8 (I tried your last command to set to en_US.UTF-8. It didn't stick, and neither are German!)

Comment: Code pages are something else. The `wsl` command runs on the host system and is not affected by WSL distribution settings.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @DanielB, wasn't sure about it as I don't play around much on Windows boxes.